# Continuously read buffer stops App

Tags: android, inputstream, android-asynctask

My App recieves a neverending datastream from a bluetooth device.
I am reading this stream in a while(true) loop and can see the read data in my log.
The problem is, that my device is not responding anymore. Is there a (hopefully) simple way to let the application read the stream in the background?

Thanks!
Christian.

@boulder:
Sorry, I don't really understand that AsynkTask class. :(
Can you please help me with this code putting it in the background?
Thank you very much!

```
                try {
                while (true) 
                {               
                    read = isBT.read(msgBuffer);
                    connected = true;
                    StringBuilder strBuffer = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i<read; i++) 
                    {
                        int b = msgBuffer[i];
                        strBuffer.append(b);
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG,"++++++ Read "+ read + " Bytes: " + strBuffer.toString());
                }
            }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d(TAG," +++ IOException ++++", e);
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this will be helpful http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Handler example:

```
private static final String CONTENT_TAG = "content";

// Call this from datastream thread to post data 
private void postProgress(String aBufferContent) {
    // Wrapping data in bundle
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString(CONTENT_TAG, aBufferContent);

    // Sending message to handler
    final Message message = mProgressHandler.obtainMessage();
    message.setData(bundle);
    mProgressHandler.sendMessage(message);
}

// This will be executed in UI thread. Do you GUI update job here
private final Handler mProgressHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        final String streamContent = msg.getData().getString(CONTENT_TAG);
        myTextView.setText(streamContent);
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks boulder. Looks interesting. I will try it using the AsyncTask class with the method doInBackground(). Is this the right way?

Comment: Yeah that's right. And post you progress to UI thread using Handler and Message classes. BTW i think it's better to spawn you own Thread with Runnable for this job since AsyncTask is designed for small tasks mostly not for those running prolonged period of time. And feel free to upvote and accept my answer if you find it helpful =)

Comment: Thank you! The code is now running in his own thread and it works now :)

Comment: @boulder: As mentioned before, the thread runs, but I'm not able to update my TextView. I know it must be done with handlers (google is my friend :)) but I can't get it to work. Can you please show me a small example with my code? Thanks again :)

Comment: Updated my answer with Handler example.